# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IMS.Models.Dealer'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, invalidoperationexception

I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but none of them could solve my problem.

**When I access** the URL: http://localhost:42626/dealer/edit/2

**Error occurs:**

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IMS.Models.Dealer'.

**DealerController Code:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int DealerId = 0)
{
    //get from database
    Models.Dealer dealer = new Models.Dealer();
    string Error;
    if(dealer.GetDealer(DealerId, out Error))
        return View(dealer);
    else
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(DealerId);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.Dealer dealer)
{
    //if All validations are true
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string Error;
        //save to database
        if(dealer.Save(out Error))
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        else
        {
            TempData["EditMessage"] = "An error occured. Could not update Dealer. Details: " + Error;
            return Edit(dealer.Id);
        }
    }

    return Edit(dealer.Id);
}
```

I've created `View` with strongly typed `Models.Dealer` and template is `Edit`.

If I have defined `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`, why is it not accepting `int` and keep asking for `Dealer` model??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently if the dealer ID can't be found, you're *calling* `RedirectToAction`, but ignoring the result and then trying to return your view with the dealer ID. I suspect you want:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int dealerId = 0)
{
    //get from database
    Models.Dealer dealer = new Models.Dealer();
    string error;
    if (dealer.GetDealer(dealerId, out error))
    {
        return View(dealer);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I've updated the variable names to be more idiomatic, btw. It feels odd that a dealer itself has `GetDealer`, mind you - I'd expect some kind of `DealerService` to be provided to your controller via dependency injection, so you'd then have:

```
Dealer dealer = dealerService.GetDealer(dealerId);
```

(I'd also probably use exceptions for error handling rather than strings like this, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: In my case, the last line `return View(DealerId);` will never execute. Because in case of success, it will return `View(dealer)`, else `redirect to index`.

Comment: @Shaharyar: I suspect you'll find it *will* execute, and that's the problem... because you're calling `RedirectToAction` but not returning it. Note how in your `Edit(Dealer)` code you use `return RedirectToAction(....);` but in your `Edit(int)` code you just *call* `RedirectToAction`. Why not debug into it and find out?

Comment: Oppss! how could I forget this.. really embarrassed.. Now everything is perfect, thank you :) One more thing, how would you through the exception from the SQL side(inside the procedure)?

Comment: @Shaharyar: I would make the `GetDealer` method throw the exception. Just because it surfaces from a stored proc doesn't mean the whole world needs to see that - abstract it away.